# Alternative to robot_self_filter in ROS2

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

When porting some code from ROS Noetic to ROS2 Humble, I could not find a suitable port of [robot_self_filter](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_self_filter).

Are there modern ROS2 compatible alternatives that take a point cloud, sensor position, URDF and TF tree; and then output a filtered point cloud?